# is this program quadratic or linear?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have the following pseudocode:

```
for i=1 to 3*n
         for j=1 to i*i
                for k=1 to j
                    if j mod i=1 then
                         s=s+1
                    endif
                next k
         next j
next i
```

When I want to analyze the number of times the part s=s+1 is performed, assuming that this operation takes constant time, I end up with a quadratic complexity or is it linear? The value of n can be any positive integer.

The calculations that I made are the following:

[image]

Comment: Is it assumed that the comparison `if j mod i=1` has a negligible cost?

Comment: With respect to what? Is `n` the only "variable" here as far as the program is concerned?

Comment: @Thilo - No, you missed it. It'd be O(n^5).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not quadratic, but should at least be polynomial.

It goes through 3n iterations.

On each iteration it does 9n<sup>2</sup> more.

On each of those it does up to 9n<sup>2</sup> more.

So I think it would be O(n<sup>5</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

When talking about running time, you should always make explicit in terms of what you are defining your running time.

If we assume you are talking about your running time in terms of n, the answer is `O(n^5)`. This is because what you are doing boils down to this, when we get rid of the constant factors:

```
do n times:
   do n^2 times:
       do n^2 times:
           do something
```

And `n * n^2 * n^2 = n^5`